# useReducer - Trying to write own useReducer which will not use dispatch if component is unmounted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

could you provide your feedback on the code below:

```
export function useUnmountSafeReducer<R extends Reducer<any, any>>(
  reducer: R,
  initialState: ReducerState<R>,
  initializer?: undefined
): [ReducerState<R>, Dispatch<ReducerAction<R>>] {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(true);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setMounted(false);
    };
  }, []);

  return [state, mounted ? dispatch : () => {}];
}
```

I am trying to write own reducer which will not use dispatch if component is unmounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a ref instead of a state.

```
  const mounted = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      mounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])
```

The reason is that using `setMounted` is a memory leak used in the destroy function of `useEffect`. Keep in mind if the component is unmounted, you are not supposed to use any internal method after that. Actually avoiding the memory leak is your reason to implement this `mounted` at the first place, isn't it?

##### disabled dispatch

Now the question is can you return a new dispatch after the unmount?

```
  return [state, mounted ? dispatch : () => {}]
```

After the unmount, there probably won't be any more update to the UI . So the way to get it working is to disable the existing `dispatch` but not providing an empty one.

```
  const _dispatch = useCallback((v) => {
    if (!mounted || !mounted.current) return
    dispatch(v)
  }, [])

  return [state, _dispatch]
```

The `useCallback` there might be optional.

Comment: it shouldn't but if it does, take out of `dispatch` from the dependency array, so leaving it as `}, [])`. In theory, it shouldn't because `dispatch` is not going to change after the initial mount.

Comment: You are welcome and if you believe the above solves your problem, please accept the answer. thank you.